# Formatting Option

Tags: c#, formatting, console-application

If I have a number like: `1042.00` and I want it to become `1,042.00` what is the proper procedure. I have used `N`, and `N2` in my formatting codes with no luck. Basically I want the format such as using `C` without the dollar sign. Let me show you below.

```
fileOut.WriteLine("Standard Deviation {0,9:N2}")
```

I have multiple lines, around 200 of code with placeholders and displaying data from various arrays. I really don't want to have to go and use `String.Format` on each placeholder.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504462/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-indian-words-format-with-lakhs-and-c

Comment: One more                                          http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/45098-How-convert-Number-Word-using-C.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to format your output.

```
string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 1042.00); //1,042.00
```

You can use overloaded [`StreamWriter.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to supply `Format` as one of the arguments and do this.

```
fileOut.WriteLine("Standard Deviation {0:0,0.00}", 1042.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much on the right track. If you're working with a decimal value you'd just use:

```
decimal someDecimal = 1042.00;
fileOut.WriteLine("Standard Deviation {0:N2}", someDecimal);
```

I suspect you mean working with text inputs (not really clear from the question - please update if you have something else in mind). If this is the case then you'd want to convert it to a decimal first:

```
string someDecimalAsString = "1042.00";
fileOut.WriteLine("Standard Deviation {0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(someDecimalAsString));
```

If you're not certain of the validity of the string decimals then you may want to use TryParse instead and handle any invalid data:

```
string someDecimalAsString = "1042.00";
decimal d;
if (decimal.TryParse(someDecimalAsString, out d))
{
    fileOut.WriteLine("Standard Deviation {0:N2}", d);
}
else
{
    // handle invalid decimals
}
```